# How to toggle auto-scroll in PyCharm's 'Run' window?

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way to toggle auto-scrolling in the PyCharm 'Run' window?  When you first launch a process into the Run window, it starts in auto-scroll mode, but if you manually scroll up, it toggles auto-scroll off.  I've had no luck finding an option or button to re-enable autoscroll.

The workaround is to close/relaunch whatever process you are running, but that is often sub-optimal.

Note that my specific use case is the Django runserver command in PyCharm 3.1 (Professional Edition) on Windows.

[image]

Comment: Just a thought: scroll again to the very bottom/end

Comment: PyCham by default auto-scrolls, if by any chance you scroll up again, just scroll down it it will go back to auto-scrolling.

Comment: This actually doesn't work for me.  If I scroll to the bottom of the window, and perform some action that generates new text, it falls off the bottom.  I added a screenshot that shows that auto-scrolling didn't pick up.  The screenshot was after I had scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: So it looks like it depends on *how* you scroll to the bottom.  Clicking in the window and hitting page down appears to trigger auto-scrolling, but mouse-wheel scrolling to the bottom does not.

Comment: I have the opposite problem: I want to turn *off* auto-scrolling but scrolling up manually (either using the mouse wheel or by dragging the scroll bar) leaves auto-scroll enabled, so as soon as the next line of text gets generated I get moved to the bottom right away. How can I turn this off?

Comment: I have the same problem and also scrolling with page down does not work (I have loads of output, pressing page down will not follow up quick enough).

Answer (score 6):

You can scroll lock the console by clicking on any output line. This will keep the window from continuing to scroll, even while new lines are added below the current window's display. You can manually scroll using the arrow keys, <kbd>Pg Up</kbd>/<kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> and the mouse wheel.

If you want to resume auto-scrolling the easiest way is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to get to the bottom of the console.

If output is less frequent, you can also click the last empty line in the console to resume auto scrolling.

Finally, there is the "Scroll to the end" button that will do the same thing as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>

[image: Scroll to end]

Comment: I didn't find the button on pyCharm 3.4.1 on Windows: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dqann67mdrt5j82/temp.png

Comment: @FooBar, It's [there](http://i.imgur.com/bxKy7pU.png) on a new default Django project on 3.4.1 (Win 7) for me.